# remove text from <p> AFTER <span>

Tags: jquery

Say I have a `<p>` like so:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, <span></span>sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
```

Is it possible to delete/remove text AFTER the `<span>` ?

So the result would be:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, </p>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've no idea where even to try with this one to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zc464way/

```
$('p').each( function( index, element ) {
    var content = $(element).html();
    $(element).html( content.substring(0, content.indexOf('<span') - 1 ) );
} );
```

You could also do it a little less verbosely if you only need to effect one element, like this:

```
var content = $('p').html();
$('p').html( content.substring(0, content.indexOf('<span') - 1 ) );
```

but the first example will allow you to truncate multiple paragraph elements at once.

**Note:**  I searched for `'<span'` rather than `'<span></span>'` just to allow for a little more flexibility, in case you want to truncate the text on any span element; however, you could change this to only truncate on empty span elements by searching for `'<span></span>'` instead.

Comment: actually it is multiple elements and they might or not have a class, id etc...the first solution you offered works like a charm, will accept when it lets me.

Comment: Note this will erase all event handlers and custom data added to elements inside `p` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the content of the paragraph's html on the span and return the first match.

```js
$('p').replaceWith(function () {
    return $('p').html().split('<span></span>')[0]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, <span></span>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that `span` element and keep iterating `nextSibling` to get its following sibling nodes. Then, check if the type of those nodes is `3` (that is, a text node), and remove it.

```js
$('p').each(function(index, element) {
    var span = $(element).children('span').get(0);
    if(!span) return;
    var node, next = span.nextSibling;
    while(node = next) {
        next = node.nextSibling;
        if(node.nodeType == 3) element.removeChild(node);
    }
});
```

```js
$('p').each( function(index, element) {
    var span = $(element).children('span').get(0),
        node, next = span.nextSibling;
    while(node = next) {
        next = node.nextSibling;
        if(node.nodeType == 3) element.removeChild(node);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
  <span></span>
  sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```